# Why is removeEventListener not working?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Can anybody please tell me why the `removeEventListener` call is not working?

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eventCall, false, 0, true);

function eventCall(e:Event):void
{
    trace("event still attached");
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eventRemoved);
}

function eventRemoved():void
{
    trace("gone");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't calling `removeEventListener()` with the same callback as when you added it. It should be:

```
this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eventCall);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass function name which was assigned as listener

```
this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eventCall);
```